# What is the max number of inputs that can be entered in a keccak256(abi.encodePacked()) function?

Tags: solidity, abi, keccak, randomness, random

I'm learning to use the keccak function on an online Solidity tutorial, and seeing that this function takes three inputs:

```
uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(now, msg.sender, randNonce)))
```

made me wonder how many inputs are allowed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here abi.encodePacked no limit to number of input.It simply concatenated your input into once.

Exmaple:
As per your function.

```
now = 1647410149
msg.sender = 0x6774A9dA5152d9c4BF9c468f0748d191Ac146720
randNonce = 15456

Assume your function input types : (uint32,address,uni256)

abi.encodePacked(now, msg.sender, randNonce) = 0x62317be56774A9dA5152d9c4BF9c468f0748d191Ac1467200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003c60
```

For more read about abi.encodePacked you can refer the [solidity-docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/abi-spec.html#non-standard-packed-mode).